Efficiently Filter YouTube API Search Results by Subscriber Count
I'm using the YouTube Data API to search for channels that meet a specific subscriber count range (e.g., between 100,000 and 500,000 subscribers). However, the API consumes a lot of quota units because it searches through multiple channels, including many that don't fit my criteria, before returning a few suitable ones.
For example, I make a search request using youtube.search().list to find channels based on a keyword. After retrieving the results, I manually check the subscriber count of each channel using the youtube.channels().list method, which further consumes quota. If I search 10 channels and only 3 fit the subscriber count range, I've used 10 units, 7 of which were wasted on channels outside my target range.
Here’s a minimal reproducible example:
python
import requests

API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

def search_youtube(query, max_results=10):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
    params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
        'q': query,
        'type': 'channel',
        'maxResults': max_results,
        'key': API_KEY
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return response.json()

def get_channel_details(channel_id):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels'
    params = {
        'part': 'statistics',
        'id': channel_id,
        'key': API_KEY
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return response.json()

# Sample query and channel processing
query = 'Minecraft'
search_results = search_youtube(query)

for item in search_results.get('items', []):
    channel_id = item['id']['channelId']
    channel_details = get_channel_details(channel_id)
    subscriber_count = int(channel_details['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])

    if 100000 <= subscriber_count <= 500000:
        print(f"Channel: {item['snippet']['title']}, Subscribers: {subscriber_count}")

Here's the link to my full code on Pastebin.
Question:
Is there a more efficient way to filter channels by subscriber count from the start, or to minimize API quota usage? Can I adjust my search parameters or use a different method to reduce the number of unnecessary API calls?
Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Maybe my Stack Overflow answer 69259093 will help you.

Based on your question I think this will help you get the highest subscribed channel for your query MINECRAFT.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=minecraft&type=video&order=viewCount&part=snippet will give you a YouTube channel that has Minecraft video on it with the highest viewCount. the highest view count on a video means the channel has at least 1m+ subscribers. I don't know the other method but I used this in one of my projects for the highest subscribed channel mark with videos. Hope this will help.
here is the response of this endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=minecraft&type=video&order=viewCount&part=snippet contains channelId with the videoId that has the highest viewCount. Also, you can read this documentation carefully here
{
  "nextPageToken": "..",
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "items": [
    {
      "snippet": {
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCBP4M08ndE/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCBP4M08ndE/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCBP4M08ndE/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          }
        },
        "title": "Cave Spider Roller Coaster - Animation vs. Minecraft Shorts Ep. 14",
        "channelId": "UCbKWv2x9t6u8yZoB3KcPtnw",
        "publishTime": "2019-09-21T11:00:11Z",
        "publishedAt": "2019-09-21T11:00:11Z",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "channelTitle": "Alan Becker",
        "description": "It's like the Roller Coaster Episode except with spiders. Watch Episode 15 Here: https://youtu.be/X7Mpp35EAqI Full Animation vs."
      },
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "....",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "pCBP4M08ndE"
      }
    },
    {
      "snippet": {
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nwC_BbTrOqA/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nwC_BbTrOqA/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nwC_BbTrOqA/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          }
        },
        "title": "BEES FIGHT - Alex and Steve Life (Minecraft Animation)",
        "channelId": "UCawEP-InoKYKutsgq_vqIXA",
        "publishTime": "2020-08-02T13:00:12Z",
        "publishedAt": "2020-08-02T13:00:12Z",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "channelTitle": "Squared Media",
        "description": "Alex and Steve discover a village inhabited by Villagers and Bees living in harmony. A Witch raids the village with their mob army ..."
      },
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": ".....",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "nwC_BbTrOqA"
      }
    },
    {
      "snippet": {
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lVgjUWFSR6w/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lVgjUWFSR6w/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lVgjUWFSR6w/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          }
        },
        "title": "Minecraft NOSTALGIA  #shorts",
        "channelId": "UCapgXl5RTXwm9d5DO21jh3Q",
        "publishTime": "2022-03-25T13:48:35Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-03-25T13:48:35Z",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "channelTitle": "GEVids",
        "description": "This is Minecraft's most nostalgic and OG worlds. These don't include Minecraft 1.18 seeds, but rather worlds from ..."
      },
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "....",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "lVgjUWFSR6w"
      }
    },
    {
      "snippet": {
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gDtQ-To3iSU/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gDtQ-To3iSU/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gDtQ-To3iSU/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          }
        },
        "title": "Minecraft RTX: What if ~44 SURPRISE #Shorts",
        "channelId": "UC2gJotBXDcyOY-Ny6yDxtZg",
        "publishTime": "2023-07-26T19:07:49Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-07-26T19:07:49Z",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "channelTitle": "Teddy P",
        "description": "Minecraft is a popular video game where players explore a blocky, procedurally-generated 3D world and gather resources to craft ..."
      },
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "....",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "gDtQ-To3iSU"
      }
    },
    {
      "snippet": {
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KZKIiiSfn_0/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KZKIiiSfn_0/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KZKIiiSfn_0/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          }
        },
        "title": "MINECRAFT SKELETON RAP REMIX | &quot;I&#39;ve Got A Bone&quot; | Oxygen Beats Dan Bull Animated Music Video",
        "channelId": "UC1hkAIJnb2CSmm7SPJaPR-A",
        "publishTime": "2020-04-03T20:01:44Z",
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-03T20:01:44Z",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "channelTitle": "Dan Bull",
        "description": "New animated music video featuring the Allay. Go and watch now! ▻ https://youtu.be/MjtlV-r37Gg REMIX! Creeper Rap."
      },
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "....",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "KZKIiiSfn_0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "regionCode": "ZZ",
  "etag": "lUYbeeZcU0qLv4YSrvA_NMa6s6g",
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 5,
    "totalResults": 1000000
  }
}


Thanks for sharing this method. It’s an interesting approach, especially when looking for channels with very large subscriber counts. However, I'm trying to narrow down my search to channels with a specific range of subscribers (e.g., 100,000 to 500,000). Do you happen to know if there’s a way to filter for this more directly or perhaps optimize API usage in such cases? Thanks!
